# The better way to build a VueJs Website (Framework easily deployable)

Tags: vue.js, deployment, static, server-side-rendering

Hey i search a powerful web framework with some specific features :

- VueJS support (single file / template)
- ServerSideRendering
- Easy deployment (with Now, Netlify, etc..)
- Powerful dynamic routes management

### Why not Nuxt.Js

Because Nuxt does not support dynamic routes when the app is generated (it does not define routes automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vue-cli-3` and generate a project with all the bells and whistles (`vuex`, `vue-router`, `typescript`, `SPA`, `unit testing`, etc).  Then add Vuetify or another similiar Material Design framework to spruce up the UI.

Of course this is `opinion based` and your question will most likely get pulled down soon :)